# Tumour cells and ResNet

Tags: neural-networks, classification, image-processing, auc, high-dimensional

A patient is represented by a set of images (1000 at maximum) of his tissues of either healthy or tumour cells. A patient is classified as 1 if at least one of the images shows tumour cells.
These images are not available but ResNet features are available for each of the images that have been extracted using ResNet50 pre-trained on the ImageNet dataset. We also have as a label not the annotation for each image but only whether or not a patient has cancer cells.
The aim is to determine whether or not a new patient represented by a maximum of 1000 images has cancer cells.
I have tried several classifiers as a logistic regression on the mean per patient of the ResNet features but I only get a maximum AUC of 0.7. Do you have an idea for improvement?

There are as a training set about 300 patients each represented by 2048 (ResNet features) * 1000 (number of images sometimes a little less).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, what you have done is feature extraction, where the weights are not derived from your dataset. To improve performance, you want the model to learn parameters suitable to your dataset.
Have you tried **retraining** the pre-trained ResNet-50 with your dataset? Here you can first try without freezing any layer. This would mean that **all** the weights would be recomputed, this would be a computationally intensive process. Alternatively, you could freeze a few initial layers to speed up your training process.

I have actually worked with ResNet-50 in detecting tumor cells from a mixed population containing tumor cells and white blood cells and found that the performance improved when I retrained the Network. No layers were frozen.

Hope this helps.

Best
Ani